# how do I use Regular Expressions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hta, jscript

I used it in C#

```
var validString = new Regex(@"^[a-z][a-z\d!@#$%\^&*()\-+]{0,7}$(?<=\d\D+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I am trying to enforce the following rules for password creation

```
•Not have upper-case letters. 
•Begin with a letter. 
•Have at least 1 digit(s) not at the beginning and end. 
•Have up to 8 alphanumeric 
•Does NOT have any symbols like @#$ characters (symbols like !@#$%^&*()-+).
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I dont know how to use it Javascript

Comment: JavaScript does not have look behinds, that is one problem and Google JavaScript regular expression to learn how to use Regular Expressions in JavaScript. :)

Comment: @Josh - I've spent all morning looking it up. I wouldn't have posted here if a simple google, bing search had provided the answers.

Comment: Helps to show what you tried!

Comment: But.. simple Google search *does* provide the answers in this case.

Comment: @epascarello I had no idea what Look behinds are. I'm looking it up on Google

Comment: Look behind is `(?<=` in the reg exp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost identical, except for:

- `new RegExp` instead of `new Regex`
- No `@` before the string
- You can't use constants for options, only a string with option letters
- You can't use lookbehinds.

Alternatively use a regex literal:

```
var validString = /^[a-z](?=[a-z]*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{0,6}[a-z]$/;
```

Note I changed your regex, since you basically say you can't have digits at the start or end. I used a lookahead instead to ensure there was a number in there.

Answer (score 2):

The same regex can be used (provided it is valid). As for how to use it is shown below:

```
var re = /^[a-z][a-z\d!@#$%\^&*()\-+]{0,7}$(?<=\d\D+)/;
var test = re.test(password);  // will store a bool value whether the password is valid or not.
```

Comment: Fails. There are no lookbehinds in JS regexes.

Comment: That's what i was exactly about to tell.

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend: http://www.diveintojavascript.com/articles/javascript-regular-expressions

Also, you can use `match`:

```
str.match(pattern)
```

Enjoy.